# Isolated points of the closure of a set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$. By $cl(A)$, I mean the closure of $A$.

I know that any isolated point of $cl(A)$ is an isolated point of $A$. A proof is here : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Isolated_Point_of_Closure_is_Isolated_Point_of_Subspace

Now, is it also true that any isolated point of $A$ is an isolated point of $cl(A)$ ? If not in general, is it at least true in some spaces $X$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s true in all $T_1$ spaces. Suppose that $x$ is an isolated point of $A$; then there is an open $U\subseteq X$ such that $U\cap A=\{x\}$. Let $y\in U\setminus\{x\}$; if $X$ is $T_1$, $U\setminus\{x\}$ is an open nbhd of $y$ disjoint from $A$, so $y\notin\operatorname{cl}A$. Thus, $U\cap\operatorname{cl}A=\{x\}$, and $x$ is still isolated in $\operatorname{cl}A$.

It can fail if $X$ is not $T_1$. Let

$$\tau=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{U\subseteq\Bbb N:0\in U\text{ and }\Bbb N\setminus U\text{ is finite}\}\;.$$

$\tau$ is a $T_0$ topology on $\Bbb N$ that is not $T_1$. Let $A=\{0\}$; certainly $0$ is an isolated point of $A$, but $\operatorname{cl}A=\Bbb N$, and $0$ is not isolated in $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Isn't 0 isolated in $\mathbb{N}$ with this topology since $\{0 \}$ is open ?

Comment: @Vandrin: Yes, and I don’t know what I was thinking. I’ve fixed it now, barring another mental hiccup. Thanks!